# Is an uncanny valley of consciousness upload feasible?

Tags: consciousness

I am interested in exploring the idea of the development of consciousness uploading/brain scanning technologies. Exploring the alpha stages of the technologies. So, you might get a partial consciousness or brain scan and the gaps in the scan might be filled in with guesses or chatbot-like technology that might try to simulate that part of a human consciousness.

In my world I am proposing a brain scanning technology that might cost as much as a house, or peoples entire life savings. That could offer a sort of immortality by digitizing your consciousness shortly after your death.

But the technology creates an incomplete copy of you and fills in the blanks.

So, maybe your favorite color is red before being scanned, but the scan misses that bit of information and so it sets your favorite color to blue instead.

Maybe you're not good at math, but the scan doesn't do well in that part of your brain, so it adds in a generic math plugin to your digital consciousness.

My thinking is that even if people know the scan is a bad copy of your consciousness they would still choose the scan when the only other option is death, and that when death is the alternative people would pay their entire life savings.

Comment: unless you clarify what you are stating, it is really hard to understand what you are asking. i.e. this sentence "Exploring the alpha stages of the technologies. So, you might get a partial consciousness or brain scan and the gaps in the scan might be filled in with guesses or chatbot-like technology that might try to simulate that part of a human consciousness."

Comment: I would suggest you [edit] your question to specify what, exactly, you are asking. Your title appears to be a collection of words that try to form a sentence, and your question body has no question at all.

Comment: What would be the next step after uploading a consciousness? Would it be implanted into a robot that could function like a human in society? Would it be held on a laptop in the family home and turned on occasionally when the family want to talk to it? Would it just be stored indefinitely until the technologies allow for implanting in a robot?

Comment: Please do some basic research before diving into deep phylosophical and psychological problems; in particular, I just don't see how a "favorite color" or a "skill in mathematics" related to _consciouness_. [Consciousness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consciousness) is (warning of massive mechanistic reduction) the state of being aware, or, in other contexts, the ability to form moral judgements. Favorite colors and being good at math are part of a person's [personality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personality).

Comment: I think user is just asking if such a flawed technology's mainstream adoption is feasible/likely, and is assuming memory, and the rest of a brain's contents, would be included in the scanning and simulation of a consciousness.

Answer (score 2):

## People will always try to become immortal in any sense that is possible

Throughout history many people tried to become immortal in some way:

- pharaohs built great monuments where they were buried after their death so taht people would always remember them
- some people tried to built an empire and survive in the books of history as great leaders
- some people are creating beautiful art, hoping that their art will survive longer than they do

In our current time people are freezing themselves to become unfrozen once technology developed enough that they won't have to fear death anymore. There are many ways in which people are trying to become immortal and they have always thought of new ways. Look at all the religions with their immortal gods which are greater than every human - who wouldn't want to be greater than everyone else?

People in the future will find your proposal to be very interesting. Some will hope they are lucky and everything important will be fine. Others hope that later iterations of your technology will fix these bugs and recreate them perfectly. Some will accept that they will never be truly immortal, but they still want to survive longer. Everyone wants others to remember them. To leave something on earth that will last the ages.

Some people will be afraid. There are always people who are afraid and these people will fight your invention. But all in all there is a good chance that partially uploaded brains will become a massive trend in our society if that is ever to occur.